# Get the set of instruction of all method separately

Tags: listener, antlr4, visitor-pattern

There is my grammar of JCA File :

```
methodBody : stackMethod localMethod  descriptorMethod* instructionMethod*  ;

stackMethod : '.stack' NUMBER ';' ;

localMethod : '.locals' NUMBER ';' ;

descriptorMethod : '.descriptor' typeJCA ';' qualifiedNumber ';';

instructionMethod : 
        ('L' NUMBER ':')? op=instruction+
        ;

instruction : 
        qualifiedID ('L'? NUMBER)* ';'
        |'.'qualifiedID '{' (('L' NUMBER) | NUMBER)* ';' '}'
        ;
```

I wish to get the instruction of all methods (instructionMethod*) separately. With listeners or visitors

Example :

```
@Override
public void enterInstructionMethod(InstructionMethodContext ctx) {
    //Print all instruction+ (one by one in a loop or any way)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I found a solution (Trivial solution)

First you have to listen to

```
    @Override
    public void enterInstruction(InstructionContext ctx) {

    }
```

And secondly you have to listen to

```
@Override
    public void exitMethodBody(MethodBodyContext ctx) {
        // Here you will have the trigger that say : hi, the instructionS that you have just read before are mine 
        //And the same think for all exitMethodBody
    }
```